# SFDX Error While pushing the code to Salesforce Org "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT"

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-error

I am getting the below error while either pushing or retrieving the code from Salesforce to VS code and vice versa. I have no proxy nothing in my system.

I have also tested on 4 Machines and 3 different OS ( Window, MAC, Linux ) and the error is the same.

```
ERROR running deploy:apex:  connect ETIMEDOUT 
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
  e

rrno: -4039,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'x.x.x.x',
  port: 443
}
```

Is anyone also facing the same issue? I am working on this since morning and now have no clue what to do.

Thanks

Comment: I was having a different issue recently with running `sfdx force:source:deploy -p .\force-app`. Looks like the cli recently switched to using REST by default for deployments, but they've still got several major kinks to work out. Can you run `sfdx config:set restDeploy=false` (or add `"restDeploy":"false"` to your sfdx-config.json) to go back to using SOAP for deployments and see if that fixes things?

Comment: It's worth trying what @DerekF mentions as a first step as the error messages have presented in different formats. You can see the issue mentioned [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/942) in general for deployment problems.

Comment: I did tried the same but no luck

Comment: I see that this error is because of long-running deployments, Recommend using force:mdapi:deploy command without -w option which returns immediately and pulls the result by using force:mdapi:deploy:report command.